# hide header box-shadow settings when scrolled down

Tags: javascript, css, box-shadow

I am using Rails framework.

The goal is to make the box-shadow of a header disappear when the user is using a specific page (search page in my case) and is scrolled maximum to the upper side.

Example:
https://media.giphy.com/media/Y0lWILbjEOc5uKqYgD/giphy.gif  - there is no shadow, until the user scrolls down.

CSS

```
nav.navbar {
  font-family: $font-family-headers;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: $body-bg;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
```

HTML.SLIM

```
nav#main-header.navbar.fixed-top.navbar-expand-md[data-user="# 
{current_user ? current_user.name : false}"]
- if t('application.image.use', locale:  :general)
```

And it doesn't look like I have anything JS related. 
Not even sure what keywords should I use to search for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

On the gif you provided, the box-shadow is always there, what's happening is that the second navbar collapses and the shadow "moves" up.

If you inspect that site's elements, you'll see that, when you scroll down, it adds some classes (for the transition of the second navbar collapse) and then a class `navbar-fixed-active` is there. When you scroll up again, that class is gone.

I'm guessing it uses JS scroll events to toggle that class off if scroll == 0 and on if scroll != 0.

Then, having or not having a shadow is just a CSS thing, you could make the element have a box-shadow property when some class is present and don't have that when the class is not there.